# Deploy app Angular 8 no Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

Olá, sou iniciante em Angular e Firebase. E estou desenvolvendo um pequeno app para a minha noiva. Um sistema onde ela vai organizar os pedidos, estoque e etc, do pequeno ateliê de bordados manuais dela. O app funciona perfeitamente em servidor local no desenvolvimento. Faço deploy no hosting Firebase, e ele funciona perfeitamente, porém, quando eu recarrega a página ele sempre retorna a página de erro. Mesmo estando logrado na aplicação. Se eu digitar a URL base do projeto no Firebase ele entra normalmente, mas ao recarregar a página ele dá erro. Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Se vc faz o deploy pelo cli do firebase tem uma hora que ele pergunta se o projeto é uma spa e vc tem que dizer que sim

Comment: @Maniero queria responder essa pergunta acho que pode ser um arquivo de configuração do projeto

Comment: @EduardoVargas dá uma olhada nisso: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7928/minha-pergunta-foi-fechada-n%c3%a3o-posso-obter-uma-resposta-ali?cb=1 O fato de poder ser algo dá menos chance ainda de ser reaberta.